# ocaml sum of two lists with different length

Tags: ocaml, addition

I tried to add two lists with different lengths using this:

```
let sumList(a,b) = match a,b with
   |[],_ -> []
   |(x::xs,y::ys)-> (x + y)::diffList(xs,ys)
```

It returns Unbound value sumList. Is it possible to do this as in Haskell: zipWith(+) a b.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the actual error is "Unbound value diffList", since you don't define `diffList` in your code.

If this is a transcription error, then the next problem is that you need to declare `sumList` as a recursive function: `let rec sumList (a, b) = ...`.

Your pattern match is not exhaustive. It fails if the first list is longer.

The Haskell `zipWith` is friendlier than the OCaml `List.map2`, which requires the lists to be the same length. I don't think there's anything so friendly in the OCaml standard library.

Comment: Sorry for typo error with diffList. But it does not works even when the second list is longer. It returns : Warning 8:this pattern-matching is not exhaustive at compile time.
Here is an example of a value that is not matched:
(_::_, [])
And in the interpreter : sumList [1;2;3] [5;7;36];; returns Unbound value sumList

Comment: Like I said, your pattern isn't exhaustive. That's the first thing to fix. You also need to declare `sumList` as a recursive function as I said. I think these two more fixes are all that's necessary.

Comment: I add another constraint:
    open Printf
let rec sumList(a,b) = match a,b with
 |_,[] -> [] 
 |[],_ -> []
 |(x::xs,y::ys)-> (x + y)::sumList(xs,ys)

let a = sumList([1;2;24],[5;2;3;4;5])
let () = List.iter (printf "%d\ ") a
And it works. Thanks